# Strange "rubberbanding" on pointer in Loki

Tags: release-loki, touchpad

I just installed Loki the other night and I really like it so far, everything has been working right out of the box on my ThinkPad L460.

The only thing that really bothers me is the touch. Its working and so are all my thinkpad buttons, even my trackpoint is doing its job, which is very good.

The PROBLEM is, when using my touchpad i experience some strange **rubberbading**. When push the pointer to the top for instance at the end of the movement it jumps back quite a bit. This may sound like a minor issue, but it makes clicking on buttons very hard over time, because when jumping back, the pointer will most of the time come off the button. Also it seems the touchpad is now very "sensitive" to movements of my finger, i didnt even have to move it, just rolling around or shifting its weight on the pad now causes some movement on the pointer.

I was very irritated, because I never had that kind of problem before, not on windows and also not on Linux Mint which I was using before. Changing the sensitivity did not really help with this :/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Having the same issue here :/